# What is statistical diversity and how is it measured? (dataset with properties of materials)

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics, diversity

I'm curious how one would define and measure statistical diversity for a research project of mine.

My motivation is to understand the statistical space of materials. Each material has a set of properties associated with it. Out of the set of all materials, I would like to develop a subset that accurately represents the whole. My understanding is that I will need to maximize diversity in order to develop an unbiased set. For example, this set might be used as a training set for machine learning, etc ...

I would love it if anyone could recommend resources to progress further, and advice on whether I am even approaching this project from the proper direction.

Comment: Could you tell us where this term "diversity" appears and what its definition might be?  Your use of it suggests you might actually be concerned about *representativeness.*

Comment: @whuber Ah, yes! From an initial search, representativeness does seem to fit what I'm looking for. Using the term 'diversity' was just my attempt to characterize the problem. Would you happen to know any resources on selecting a representative sample from a large dataset? Thanks!

Comment: What would it mean for you, in your context, for a subset to "accurately represent the whole"?

Comment: @gung In term of materials, let's suppose I'm only interested in the electrical conductivity of a material. Then an accurate representation of the whole would include a conductor, insulator, and semiconductor. Just extend this idea to the many properties of a material that are measured experimentally.

Comment: I'm only vaguely clear on "conductor, insulator, and semiconductor", TBH. If all you want are 3 components, 1 of each type, why not just pick 3? Can you provide a *statistical* descriptions of what it would mean for a subset to "accurately represent the whole"?

Comment: @gung I would pick those 3 in that case. However reality is more complex and each material has a set of properties {a,b,c,d,...x,y,z}. You can think of a material space where materials occupy locations based on their properties. There are thousands upon thousands of materials. I want to be able to select a smaller set that occupies this 'space' to a similar extent. Is that clear?

Comment: Could you pick 1 of each? Would picking items at regular intervals along a grid work? Can you provide a small example dataset where an intuitive strategy can be demonstrated & shown why it wouldn't be good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use multivariate analysis on your dataset of thousands of materials measured on a lot of variables.  Some ideas:

1. try cluster analysis, then sampling a few materials from each cluster could maybe work as a "representative sample".
2. some variant of multidimensional scaling (MDS), which is a way of finding coordinates for each material in some coordinate space of dimension $n$, such that the euclidean distances between materials represent the dissimilarity of the materials.  Then again, as above, choosing some materials which together cover most of the space.

I think that some such idea could work.